# RHEL Login error in VMware

Tags: rhel, boot, mount, vmware, reboot

I am trying to start my virtual machine (RHEL 8) in my VMware but it displays this error

[image]

Previously I tried to unmount a newly added virtual HD which worked fine

But in `lsblk -f` it was still mounted

I thought restarting would work but then it started showing that screen from the image above

Can someone tell me why am I getting this error and what are the steps to fix this

Comment: Remove `quiet` `rhgb` from grub options, boot, take a picture, edit your question and post it here.

Comment: what is `quiet` `rhgb` and how can I remove them

Comment: Run the command in the error - journalctl -xb.   It could be a bad entry in fstab,  but you should see some details in the system log.

Comment: journalctl may not necessarily contain any useful info if e.g. the root partition fails to get mounted.

Comment: @user103944 you were right. It was a bad entry in `fstab` . I logged in as root in the emergency mode and removed the entry that caused the error. Now my system is working fine again. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error by removing the entry in `fstab` that I had made for the new Hard Disk Partition which was causing the error.
I realised that I was trying to `unmount` a partition with the `umount` command which was actually mounted by making an entry in `fstab`